# loopback angular sdk login error

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to log in a new user, but i have some problems.
I've created admin role, admin user, RoleMapping and the Principal. Then i've created the client services using the command below:

```
lb-ng ../server/server.js js/lb-services.js
```

When i try to login using the command

```
User.login({"email":"email","password":"password"})
```

I receive:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/login?include=user 404 (Not Found)
```

What is the query string parameter `?include=user?`

I've tried to login with PostMan and everything works correctly.
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the correct url would be `http://localhost:3000/api/users/login?include=user`

Comment: If i make the request with Postman, the URL i use is
http://localhost:3000/api/users/login.
Why i find
http://localhost:3000/users/login?include
as URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon, it seems to be a little bit old post but I had this same problem and found a solution about it.

If we check the file generated by lb-ng for login function it states:

> - Login a user with username/email and password.
>         *
>         * @param {Object=} parameters Request parameters.
>         *
>         *  - `include` – `{string=}` - Related objects to include in the response. See the description of return value for more details.
>         *   Default value: `user`.

And if we check return value's description:

> ```
>     * The response body contains properties of the AccessToken >created on login.
>     * Depending on the value of `include` parameter, the body may contain additional properties:
>     * 
>     *   - `user` - `{User}` - Data of the currently logged in user. (`include=user`)
> ```

So include=user seems to add to response a property with user logged in data in a property called "user" in this case, but you can change the property's name for whatever you want.

In my case the solution was following Robins answer, and change the default server. It seems that lb-ng solution create code to look API calls into the server where is running the client. If you use another server you must change app.config this way, stated in loopback docs:

> angular.module('my-app-module')
>    .config(function(LoopBackResourceProvider) {
>
> // Use a custom auth header instead of the default 'Authorization'
>      LoopBackResourceProvider.setAuthHeader('X-Access-Token');
>
> // Change the URL where to access the LoopBack REST API server
>      LoopBackResourceProvider.setUrlBase('http://api.example.com/');
>    });

Let the header line if you want that change, but it's mandatory to use the second line changing 'http://api.example.com' with the server you use to serve the REST API.

(Hope it helps to anyone with this problem).